# Will cookie be available when javascript is disabled at client side?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

This is one of the questions I'm asked in the interview today,

but I'm not sure of the answer.

Comment: You already have 2 bulletproof answers. **Cookies are not related to JavaScript**

Comment: You want a proof? Disable js, clean your cookies, surf a bit, open your cookie cache: full of cookies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Cookies are a browser/server http technology, completly unrelated to client-side scripting.

The main (or at least, initial) use for cookies is to set a value server-side and read it server-side.

Clients may disable cookies in their browser, though.

Comment: -1 for wrong answer. Servers can drop cookies but so can javascript. Similarly javascript can read the cookies in scope for a page. Cookies do not set any value server side.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. Bullet-proof derivation below:

> The cookie is sent as an HTTP header
>   by a web server to a web browser and
>   then sent back unchanged by the
>   browser each time it accesses that
>   server.

---

### Setting a cookie

To access the page `http://www.example.org/index.html`, browsers connect to the server `www.example.org` sending it a request that looks like the following one:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
```

The server replies by sending the requested page preceded by a similar packet of text, called 'HTTP response'. This packet may contain lines requesting the browser to store cookies:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: name=value

(content of page)
```

The server sends the line `Set-Cookie` only if the server wishes the browser to store a cookie. `Set-Cookie` is a request for the browser to store the string `name=value` and send it back in all future requests to the server. If the browser supports cookies and cookies are enabled, every subsequent page request to the same server will include the cookie. For example, the browser requests the page `http://www.example.org/spec.html` by sending the server `www.example.org` a request like the following:

```
GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: name=value
Accept: */*
```

Source and further reading: [Wikipedia: HTTP Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are just a typical HTTP header. Whenever your browser request for some website it sends request headers like following:

```
GET /questions/2476288/will-cookie-be-available-wh... 
Host: stackoverflow.com
....
Accepted-Languages: ....
Accepted-Encoding: ....
....
Cookies: cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2
```

So as you can see cookies are part of HTTP protocol not JS, however JS is able to create/remove/modify cookies. In other words: cookies are **independed** from JS.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie is set using a server-side script, the website will be able to set a cookie even if Javascript is disabled.

PHP Example:

```
setcookie('test', 'test');
```

The cookie is then sent to the site as an HTTP Header unless they're disabled in the browser. It does not matter whether Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Yes (although you won't be able to use JS to set it or read it)

Comment: What's your proof?Cookie needs to be written into client side,but is that allowed when js is disabled?

Comment: You can write cookies also server side. I don't know if they are the same thing but you can do it.